# Script to search several servers for connected client IP addresses

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a Powershell script to search 5 servers for connected client's IP addresses. There are 5 servers and clients are connected via a user tunnel and an asset one. I'm trying to make a looping script that asks for the asset number and username then searches all 5 servers then reports back the tunnel IPs.

My Powershell skills are very rudimentary. I've managed to make a script that mostly works, the trouble I seem to be having is getting the script to report negative results properly. Here's where I am so far:

```
Clear-Host
$continue = $true
while ($continue){

Write-Host "Tunnel IP finder" -ForegroundColor White
$Asset = Read-Host "Enter asset number"
$AssetAddress = "$asset.corporate.domain.com"
$User = Read-Host "Enter Username"
$Username = "$User@domain.com"
$servers = "RRAS_01","RRAS_02","RRAS_03","RRAS_04","RRAS_05"

Write-Host ""
    $data1 = Foreach ($Server1 in $Servers)
    {
    Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics -computername $Server1 | Where {$_.UserName -eq $AssetAddress} | Select ClientIPAddress | findstr /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"
    }

    foreach($item1 in $data1){
    
        if($item1.length -gt 1){
        Write-Host "Asset tunnel IP is $item1"-ForegroundColor Green}
            }
        if($item1.length -LT 1){
        Write-Host "Unable to locate asset on RRAS servers"-ForegroundColor yellow
            }

    $data2 = Foreach ($Server2 in $Servers)
    {
    Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics -computername $Server2 | Where {$_.UserName -eq $Username} | Select ClientIPAddress | findstr /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"
    }

    foreach($item2 in $data2){
    
        if($item2.length -gt 1){
        Write-Host "User tunnel IP is $item2"-ForegroundColor Green}
            }
        if($item2.length -lt 1){
        Write-Host "Unable to locate user on RRAS servers"-ForegroundColor yellow

            }
Write-Host ""
}
```

When I search for an asset number and username of someone who is connected it is reporting the results back like this:

```
Tunnel IP finder
Enter asset number: N02312
Enter Username: SmithJ

Asset tunnel IP is 10.120.xxx.xxx 
User tunnel IP is 10.120.xxx.xxx

AOVPN Tunnel IP finder
Enter asset number:
```

Which is what I was looking to achieve, it displays the IPs and loops to enter more if needed, however when I input details that is not currently connected I get:

```
Tunnel IP finder
Enter asset number: 
Enter Username:


AOVPN Tunnel IP finder
Enter asset number:
```

It's not reporting the negative results. When I take the scripting off and just have it dump what it thinks `$item1/2` is supposed to be it prints nothing, so as far as I can tell `$item1/2.length -LT 1` should be doing it.

I've tried experimenting with `Else` and `Elseif`, but I can't seem to make those work. There are probably better ways of doing this, but my Powershell is still very basic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you loop through a collection that has `$null` value the `$item.length` will be equal to `1`, not to `0` and its value will not be equal to `$null`. Maybe that´s what happening to you.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $x = $null
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $x.length
0

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $arr = {$null}
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $arr.length
1
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $arr | % {$_.length}
1
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $arr | % {$_ -eq $null}
False
```

In your code you only check for the length to be either less or greater than 1 so in the case of the length being equal to 1 it would not print anything. Since the `$null` check doesnt work I think the best option would be to change the second comparison operator to less or equal instead of less than:

```
if($item1.length -LE 1){
    Write-Host "Unable to locate asset on RRAS servers"-ForegroundColor yellow
        }
```